# I can log in with my password, but it's not accepted as valid for authentication

Tags: 12.04, password, authentication

I can log in with my password just fine, but when trying to use sudo to run commands or authenticating to install software, my password does not work and my account is an administrator account. Further more, when I try to change my password with "passwd" in recovery mode, I get "Authentication token manipulation error." I've just installed 12.04, so I'm not sure what I could've done to break the system.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/152793/password-not-working-for-sudo-authentication-failure

Comment: Are you able to run commands as root using `pkexec` instead of `sudo`? (You can try a harmless command like `pkexec ls` to see.) If so, what happen when you try to change your password using `pkexec passwd $USER`. *[I'm posting this as a comment rather than an answer because it's more likely to reveal useful diagnostic information, than to actually solve the problem.]* You can edit your question to add this information. (Unless it solves the problem; then comment about that and I'll repost this as an answer. But that will probably not happen, not quite yet.)

Comment: OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years to respond to comments. This question is about EOL version and doesn't have any answers. As such VTC as `not reproducible`